# Pandas not installing in 64 bit windows

Tags: pandas, anaconda

I recently installed a new verion of Anaconda 3 4.2 on a windows laptop.
All the packages work fine , but pandas never worked for me from day 1.
So i thought of uninstalling and installing a new version of pandas 0.19

```
While using pip:
C:\Users\>python -m pip install --user pandas
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-0.19.2-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3-4.2\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "D:\Anaconda3-4.2\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "D:\Anaconda3-4.2\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "D:\Anaconda3-4.2\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "D:\Anaconda3-4.2\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "D:\Anaconda3-4.2\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 821, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "D:\Anaconda3-4.2\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 663, in unpack_http_url
    unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
  File "D:\Anaconda3-4.2\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 599, in unpack_file
    flatten=not filename.endswith('.whl')
  File "D:\Anaconda3-4.2\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 499, in unzip_file
    fp = open(fn, 'wb')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-h5ip5q8f\\pandas\\pandas/io/tests/data/blank.xls

While using conda :
An unexpected error has occurred.
Please consider posting the following information to the
conda GitHub issue tracker at:

    https://github.com/conda/conda/issues



Current conda install:

               platform : win-64
          conda version : 4.3.8
       conda is private : False
      conda-env version : 4.3.8
    conda-build version : 2.0.2
         python version : 3.5.2.final.0
       requests version : 2.12.4
       root environment : D:\Anaconda3-4.2  (writable)
    default environment : D:\Anaconda3-4.2
       envs directories : D:\Anaconda3-4.2\envs
          package cache : D:\Anaconda3-4.2\pkgs
           channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch
            config file : None
           offline mode : False
user-agent : conda/4.3.8 requests/2.12.4 CPython/3.5.2 Windows/7
Windows/6.1.7601

D:\Anaconda3-4.2\Scripts\conda-script.py install pandas
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Anaconda3-4.2\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 617, in conda_exception_handler
        return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "D:\Anaconda3-4.2\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 137, in _main
        exit_code = args.func(args, p)
File "D:\Anaconda3-4.2\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_install.py", line 80, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'install')
File "D:\Anaconda3-4.2\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 347, in install
        execute_actions(actions, index, verbose=not context.quiet)
File "D:\Anaconda3-4.2\lib\site-packages\conda\plan.py", line 837, in execute_actions
        execute_instructions(plan, index, verbose)
File "D:\Anaconda3-4.2\lib\site-packages\conda\instructions.py", line 258, in execute_instructions
        cmd(state, arg)
File "D:\Anaconda3-4.2\lib\site-packages\conda\instructions.py", line 118, in UNLINKLINKTRANSACTION_CMD
        txn = UnlinkLinkTransaction.create_from_dists(index, prefix, unlink_dists, link_dists)
      File "D:\Anaconda3-4.2\lib\site-packages\conda\core\link.py", line 121, in create_from_dists
        for dist, pkg_dir in zip(link_dists, pkg_dirs_to_link))
      File "D:\Anaconda3-4.2\lib\site-packages\conda\core\link.py", line 121, in <genexpr>
        for dist, pkg_dir in zip(link_dists, pkg_dirs_to_link))
      File "D:\Anaconda3-4.2\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\disk\read.py", line 71, in read_package_info
        index_json_record = read_index_json(extracted_package_directory)
      File "D:\Anaconda3-4.2\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\disk\read.py", line 94, in read_index_json
        with open(join(extracted_package_directory, 'info', 'index.json')) as fi:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\Anaconda3-4.2\\pkgs\\pandas-0.19.2-np111py35_1\\info\\index.json
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to install Pandas as a regular user, and therefore cannot change the contents of Anaconda installation folder (where Python installed packages live). You need to run CMD or PowerShell (whichever you are using) as an administrator. Right-click on its shortcut in the start menu and click "Run as administrator", then run again the same command.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Anaconda package manager - `conda` instead of pip:

```
C:\> conda install pandas
```

Comment: An unexpected error has occurred.
Current conda install:
platform : win-64
conda version : 4.3.8
conda is private : False
conda-env version : 4.3.8
conda-build version : 2.0.2
python version : 3.5.2.final.0
root environment : D:\Anaconda3-4.2  (writable)
user-agent : conda/4.3.8 requests/2.12.4 CPython/3.5.2 Windows/7 Windows/6.1.7601
D:\Anaconda3-4.2\Scripts\conda-script.py install pandas
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: D:\\Anaconda3-4.2\\pkgs\\pandas-0.19.2-np111py35_1\\info\\index.json